# How to calculate the element scroll height and scroll when move mouse in another element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

- i'm trying to create a select list and custom scrollbar what i did at the first is when the user scrolling the element the custom scrollbar move to the scolled position normally without any problem you can find it at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahmed01x/qekwL6p4/1/)
- now i want to hide the browser scrollbar and apply scolling inside the select menu from this custom scroll bar i tried the following

```
let scrollbarConatiner = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbar-conatiner')[0],
menuItemsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-items-container")[0]
scrollbarConatiner.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
   let scrollbar =  this.getElementsByClassName("scrollBar")[0]
   let y = e.offsetY
   console.log(menuItemsContainer.scrollHeight, menuItemsContainer.clientHieght, e.offsetY)
   menuItemsContainer.scrollTop = y;
})
```

- but it's scrolling just for the `clientHieght` when i want it to scroll and move the scrollbar to the `menuItemsContainer`  `scrollHeight` i don't know the right way to apply this custom scrolling can anyone help me to make it work

> here's the whole code

**HTML**

```
<div id="select">choose...</div>
<div id="select-menu">
    <!-- Scrollbar -->
    <div class="scrollbar-conatiner">
        <div class="scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- menu items -->
    <div class="menu-items-container">
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Facebook</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>YouTube</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Twitter</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Pinterest</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Instagram</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Raddit</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Facebook</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>YouTube</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Twitter</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Pinterest</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Instagram</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Raddit</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Facebook</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>YouTube</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Twitter</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Pinterest</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Instagram</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-items">
            <span>Raddit</span>
            <span class="circle">
                <span class="circlein"></span>
            </span>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#select {
    background: #1c1d22;
    color: #999;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}

#select:before {
    content: "";
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #818181;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 42%;
}

#select-menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.menu-items-container {
    background: dodgerblue;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 360px;
}

.menu-items {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 20px 90px 20px 20px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-items:hover {
    background: #333
}

.menu-items:hover .circle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 4px rgba(233, 244, 255, 0.3);
    top: 30%
}

.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    right: 25px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.circlein {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 65%;
    width: 65%;
    background: skyblue;
    display: none;
}

.scrollbar-conatiner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 12px;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.3);
    right: 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}

.scrollbar {
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 35px;
    background: #333;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;

    }
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    from {
        opacity: 1;

    }

    to {
        opacity: 0;

    }
}
```

**JS**

```
let select = document.getElementById('select'),
    selectMenu = document.getElementById("select-menu"),
    menuItemsContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-items-container")[0],
    menuItems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-items"),
    scrollbarConatiner = document.getElementsByClassName('scrollbar-conatiner')[0]

//show scrollbar only when elements more than 6
if (menuItems.length > 6) {
    scrollbarConatiner.style.display = 'block'
} else {
    scrollbarConatiner.style.display = 'none'
}

select.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //select menu
    selectMenu.style.display = 'flex'

    //scrollbar
    scrollbarConatiner.style.height = menuItemsContainer.offsetHeight + "px";

    //select-menu items
    menuItemsContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    menuItemsContainer.style.transition = '0.5s';
});

$(".menu-items").click(function() {
    //select-menu
    selectMenu.style.display = 'none'

    //set text of choosed element
    select.innerText = this.innerText.trim()

    //add circle for choosed 
    $(".circlein").hide();
    $(this).find(".circlein").show(10)
});

$("#select-menu").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.id === $(this).attr("id")) {
        $(this).fadeOut(40);
    }
});


menuItemsContainer.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var y = menuItemsContainer.scrollTop;
    var z = menuItemsContainer.scrollHeight - menuItemsContainer.clientHeight;
    var q = (y / z) * 70
    $(".scrollbar").css({
        top: q + "%"
    })
});

scrollbarConatiner.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    let scrollbar = this.getElementsByClassName("scrollBar")[0]
    let y = e.offsetY
    console.log(menuItemsContainer.scrollHeight, e.offsetY, menuItemsContainer.clientHeight)
    menuItemsContainer.scrollTop = y;
})
```